# Using Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am very new to webpack and stuffs, I need a solution to separate **base href** of `index.html` and  src for **bundle.js**, for development and production as both are different.

**For Development**

**base href** = localhost

**src** = /bundle.js

**For Production**

**base href** = server url

**src** = /dist/bundle.js

To solve the above problem I am trying to use **HtmlWebpackPlugin**, following is the **webpack.config.js** setting

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use:[
      {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options:{
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
       }
      },
     ]
  },
  plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       }),
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template:'index.html',
          inject:'head',
          hash: true,
          baseHref: 'http://localhost:8030/'
      })
  ]
};
```

and following is the way I am trying to use **baseHref** into `index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseHref) { %>
      <base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseHref %>">
    <% } %>

    /*
       Several css are defined with relative path here
    */
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

I am receiving following error by using above settings

[image]

I need help to know what I am doing wrong here?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `html-loader` installed?

Comment: nope it is not installed, does it make any difference @Prakashsharma ?

Comment: I would say use `ejs` template instead. You dont need any loader for that. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md

Comment: The link says that if you use html template then you need `html-loader` for that.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was missing `test: /\.js$/,` for `babel-loader` it worked for html, though I changed to ejs now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/212

This issue on Github suggests renaming your "index.html" file to "index.ejs".

This appears to be because webpack is trying to apply the Babel transpiler to your html file and it fails, the ".ejs" extension will prevent it.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was missing `test: /\.js$/,` for `babel-loader` it worked for html, though I changed to ejs now. Thanks for help.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but your config didn't have a babel-loader!

Answer (score 2):

Main purpose of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` is to recognise your entry files and place them into appropriate place (dist/index.html). So you don't need to that manually.

If you don't have `HtmlWebpackPlugin` you should to remember each file which you use in application and manually add them into `index.html`.